Are all jetliners equipped with cabin air filtration system?
I want to know if all commercial jetliners are now equipped with cabin air filters or not. I knew that, till some recent period, only the cockpit had this equipment and not all aircrafts.

Not all planes have HEPA filters, but since the COVID-19 pandemic, all new airliners and most major airline fleets have been equipped with HEPA filters throughout the full cabin.
So anything that rolls off Boeing and Airbus production lines has HEPA filters for the full cabin since COVID.
Some of the older planes like American Airlines Regional jets don't have HEPA filters but many of these old planes are being retrofitted.
Lufthansa, ANA, Southwest, and many other airlines have all their planes with HEPA filters.

Since 1988 on Airbus single aisle aircraft and since 1994 for the entire fleet (see figure 5), Airbus installs HEPA (High Efficiency Particulate Air) filters for the recirculated air providing more than 99.9% filtration efficiency (for 0.3 micrometer particles as most penetrating particle size). It is important to understand that the filtration efficiency for these filters is not only based on direct interception or sieving for larger particles but also on other effects like impaction and diffusional interception for smaller particles like bacteria and viruses.

I got this information from here
Here's another document from IATA on this matter - Cabin air quality
